# Interpreting results of sequence mining with SPADE

Tags: r, algorithm, sequences

Please help to interpret the results of SPADE frequent sequence mining algorithm (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/arulesSequences/docs/cspade​)

With support = 0.05:

```
s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.05), control = list(verbose = TRUE))
```

I get, for example, these sequences:

```
4          <{C},{V}> 0.15644023
5            <{C,V}> 0.73127376
```

Looks like these are the same sequences, aren't they? How <{C},{V}> semantically differes from <{C,V}> ? Any real life examples?

From Spade paper (M. J. Zaki. (2001). SPADE: An Efficient Algorithm for Mining Frequent Sequences. Machine Learning Journal, 42, 31--60):

"An input-sequence C is said to contain another sequence A, if A is a
subsequence of the input-sequence C. The support or frequency of a sequence is the the total number of input-sequences in the database D that contain A."

Then, for example, if:

```
            sequence    support
1              <{C}> 1.00000000
```

Does it mean that sequence <{C}> is contained in *all* sequences in database D, correct?

Complete output that I get from my data:

```
> as(s1, "data.frame")
            sequence    support
1              <{C}> 1.00000000
2              <{L}> 0.20468120
3              <{V}> 0.73127376
4          <{C},{V}> 0.15644023
5            <{C,V}> 0.73127376
6            <{L,V}> 0.07882027
7          <{V},{V}> 0.13343431
8        <{C,V},{V}> 0.13343431
9      <{C},{C},{V}> 0.05558572
10         <{C,L,V}> 0.07882027
11       <{V},{C,V}> 0.13343431
12       <{C},{C,V}> 0.15644023
13     <{C,V},{C,V}> 0.13343431
14   <{C},{C},{C,V}> 0.05558572
15         <{C},{L}> 0.05738619
16           <{C,L}> 0.20468120
17       <{C},{C,L}> 0.05738619
18         <{C},{C}> 0.22128547
19         <{L},{C}> 0.06233031
20         <{V},{C}> 0.16921494
21     <{V},{V},{C}> 0.05047012
22     <{V},{C},{C}> 0.06233031
23       <{C,V},{C}> 0.16921494
24     <{C},{V},{C}> 0.05781487
25   <{C,V},{V},{C}> 0.05047012
26   <{V},{C,V},{C}> 0.05047012
27   <{C},{C,V},{C}> 0.05781487
28 <{C,V},{C,V},{C}> 0.05047012
29       <{C,L},{C}> 0.06233031
30     <{C},{C},{C}> 0.07882027
31   <{C,V},{C},{C}> 0.06233031
> summary(s1)
set of 31 sequences with

most frequent items:
      C       V       L (Other) 
     27      22       8       8 

most frequent elements:
    {C}     {V}   {C,V}     {L}   {C,L} (Other) 
     21      12      12       3       3       2 

element (sequence) size distribution:
sizes
 1  2  3 
 7 13 11 

sequence length distribution:
lengths
 1  2  3  4  5 
 3  9 12  6  1 

summary of quality measures:
    support       
 Min.   :0.05047  
 1st Qu.:0.05760  
 Median :0.07882  
 Mean   :0.17121  
 3rd Qu.:0.16283  
 Max.   :1.00000  

includes transaction ID lists: FALSE 

mining info:
 data ntransactions nsequences support
    x         61000      34991    0.05
> ​
```

Comment: Hello there! . Although ,I can create a  transaction matrix from my data , I haven't been able to run spade due to the error invalid 'eid'.
heres the thread , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034239/warning-message-in-read-baskets-in-arulessequences-in-r ...would you please help me out??

Answer (score 1):

When using SPADE algorithm, remember that you are also dealing with temporal data (i.e. you can know the order or time of occurrence of the item).

> Looks like these are the same sequences, aren't they? How <{C},{V}>
>   semantically differs from <{C,V}> ? Any real life examples?

In your example, <{C}, {V}> means that item C occurred first, and then item V; <{C, V}> means than item C and V occurred at the same time.

> Then, for example, if:
>
> ```
>             sequence    support
> 1              <{C}> 1.00000000
> ```
>
> Does it mean that sequence <{C}> is contained in all sequences in
>   database D, correct?

An item with support value of 1 means that it happened (in a market basket analysis example) in ALL transactions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like these are the same sequences, aren't they? How <{C},{V}>
>   semantically differes from <{C,V}> ? Any real life examples?

As user2552108 pointed, {C,V} implies that C and V occurred at the same time. In practice this can be used to encode multi-dimensional sequential data. For example, suppose that C was Canada and V was Vancouver. Now this could have been something like:

[{C,V,M,peanut,butter,maple_syrup}, ... , {}]

In this case, your frequent item-set can not only have single length sets like say {C}, {V}, {U}, {W}, or {X}, but also sets with length > 1 (the sets that appeared simultaneously - at the same time).

For this reason, the element in transactions/sequences are defined as sets and not single elements.

> Does it mean that sequence <{C}> is contained in all sequences in
>   database D, correct?

That's correct!